# Springboot RabbitMQ with concurrent consumers

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

i have a simple architecture, in which one of three processes (actually a spring-boot dockerized container) produces thousands of messages to a exchange/queue, and ALL three processes consume those messages.

I want the consumerside to be multi-threaded to achieve maximum throughput, but with my current configuration, i dont achieve what i want.

Here is the setup:

Listener:

```
  @RabbitListener(
    bindings = @QueueBinding(
      value = @Queue(
                value = RabbitMQConfiguration.BORD_QUEUE, 
                durable = "true", 
                arguments = @Argument(name = "x-queue-mode", value = "lazy")),
      exchange = @Exchange(value = RabbitMQConfiguration.QUEUE_EXCHANGE),
      key = "B"), 
    concurrency = "8-8")

  public void listenBordero(Long bId, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) {
    log.info("Received message: {{}}", bId);
    processor.process(bId);
  }
```

Here is the - possibly relevant - springboot application.properties configuration:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=simple
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.max-concurrency=8
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=8
```

Although i believe that not all of them are neccessary due to `@RabbitListener` annotation based configuration.

In the rabbitmq-managment i see
[image]
with state is mainly idle.

From my springboot-logs i see the threading is scarcely takeing place (the thread-name in the log only changes after doezens of lines, whereas i expect that to switch much more often).

The queue shows in the management-console:

[image]

My Expectation would be to see the Stats of the consumer on the channel-page to be much more in "running".

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
After activating debugging for spring-amqp i see multiple messages are being received, but afterwards the threads named "..Container#0-*n*" are only processed en bloc. I would have expected the output of the multiple running container-threads to be mixed up. Can this be a ThreadPool Issue?

Here is a (noise reduced) log excerpt:

```
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-7] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {436}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-5] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {450}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-12] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {414}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-11] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {418}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-8] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {432}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-2] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {456}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-15] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {469}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-16] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {394}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-13] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {409}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-4] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {452}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.418  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-9] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {431}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-10] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {420}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [tContainer#0-14] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {350}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-1] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {400}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {453}
2020-03-05 08:15:21.419  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-6] d.i.clearing.rabbit.RabbitMQListener     : Received message: {449}
... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.409  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Clearing  : Calculating {7183042} - {8330}/{5500}  
2020-03-05 08:15:26.411  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Clearing  : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.412 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Clearing  : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.413  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Clearing  : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.507  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Clearing  : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.669  WARN 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Rddel     : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:26.669  INFO 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Rddel     : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:33.012 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] de.idslogistik.clearing.api.p2.Rddel     : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:33.013 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] d.i.i.util.clearing.VerSendungTools      : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:33.013 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] d.i.i.util.clearing.VerSendungTools      : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:33.013 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] d.i.i.util.clearing.VerSendungTools      : ... Logging Noise removed
2020-03-05 08:15:33.014 DEBUG 32960 --- [ntContainer#0-3] d.i.i.util.clearing.VerSendungTools      : ... Logging Noise removed
```

Comment: With `prefetch=1` you should see messages distributed across all the consumers (at the cost of reduced performance); turn on DEBUG logging to see if it provides any clues. I am not sure what "idle" means there - I see the same thing while a consumer is processing a message. You should ask such questions (what does idle mean) on the rabbitmq-users Google group to reach the RabbitMQ engineers. Given that each consumer has an un-ack'd message; it appears they are all actually processing a message (or you haven't ack'd when using MANUAL ack mode, which would cause processing to stop).

Comment: At the risk of a downvote since it doesn't strictly answer the OPs question, have you considered using Spring Cloud Stream's Rabbit Binder? Unless you have a specific need to manage threading manually I believe it should handle threading for you. Full disclosure, I've not used SCS's RabbitMQ binder a lot, but it might be worth a shot. The refactor shouldn't be too major.

Answer (score 1):

prefetch = 1 means that the maximum number of unacknowledged messages in the current queue is at most 1.When this message is not acknowledged, the next message cannot enter the consumption queue.

Or you can consider increasing the number of consumers to speed up the processing of messages
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however, i don't think it is a raw rabbitmq issue. it seems to me like the Containers run by rabbitmq (?) are not being threaded as i would expect them to be. I have set the concurrency to 8, but i don't see 8 parallel threads (containers?).